# Unable to open the database file

Tags: c#, sqlite, connection

```
private void SetConnection()
{
     string a = string.Format(@"Data Source={0};Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;", "~/lodeDb.db");
     sql_con = new SQLiteConnection(a);
}

private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
{
     SetConnection();
     sql_con.Open();
     sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
     sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
     sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     sql_con.Close();
}
```

When I run `sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`, Sqlexception is :

> "Unable to open the database file".

"lodeDb.db" file on my hosting, I think data source is wrong. If database file in online hosting, how to set datasourse for connection? Permission file is no problem here.

Answer (score 48):

I got the same exception when trying to open databases that are on the network drive (path starts with "\\myServer\myDbFile...") and I resolved it by putting `true` to the `parseViaFramework` parameter in connection constructor.

```
sql_con = new SQLiteConnection(a, true);
```

Comment: You may also prepend UNC paths with `\\\`, as described [here](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/System-Data-SQLite-and-UNC-Paths-td72920.htm).

Comment: Updating the UNC path link. It is now here http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/System-Data-SQLite-and-UNC-Paths-td72920.html

Comment: one thing i found out.  you can still use a folder that only has a UNC path with out adding the true, if your using a relative path.   so myfolder\ok.db3 doesn't need to "parse with framework". but  \\myserver\myfolder\okay.db3  does even though it's pointing to the same file in the same location.

Answer (score 6):

It's a Connection String Issue,

**SQL Lite Connection Strings Formats**

Basic :

```
Data Source=filename;Version=3;
```

Using UTF16 :

```
Data Source=filename;Version=3;UseUTF16Encoding=True;
```

With password :

```
Data Source=filename;Version=3;Password=myPassword;
```

Using the pre 3.3x database format :

```
Data Source=filename;Version=3;Legacy Format=True;
```

With connection pooling :

```
Data Source=filename;Version=3;Pooling=False;Max Pool Size=100;
```

Read only connection :

```
Data Source=filename;Version=3;Read Only=True;
```

---

**EDIT 1 :**
Connecting to remote database differs, you must check the following.

1. Firewall port permissibility.
2. Company/Host providing database is allowing remote connection.

Comment: Sorry but when i run application in my local computer, this app is running very well. But i deploy app to server ---> error.Can you tell me how to connect to database

Answer (score 5):

My problem is solved when add "Journal Mode=Off;" in connection string

Disable the Journal File
This one disables the rollback journal entirely.

Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;Journal Mode=Off;

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it using query string like:
@"Data Source=C:\ProgramData\proj\lodeDb.db;Version=3;FailIfMissing=False"

By that, I meant that when I use the full path for the location of the DB file, it works, when I use "~/lodeDb.db" it does not work

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue on the shared hosting server, My C# code was able to read data from SQLIte db file. But while add / update data it was throwing Error "unable to open database"

I tried many options suggested on stackoverflow But after referring https://stackoverflow.com/a/17780808/2021073 and https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode I tried adding **journal mode=Off;** to the Connection string

it worked for me

sample code

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=G:\dbfolder\sqlite3.db;Version=3;Mode=ReadWrite;journal mode=Off;", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
var index = dialog.FileName.IndexOf('\\'); example: "C:\TEST.DB"
if (0 != index) {
    Models.Context.CreateDatabase(dialog.FileName);
    OpenProject(dialog.FileName);
}
else //example: "\\Ceng\Share\MyPC"
{
    var path = dialog.FileName.Replace('\\', '/');
    Models.Context.CreateDatabase(path);
    OpenProject(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by setting up System.Data.SQLite dll=>properties=>Copy local=>"True"