# SQLIte unable to open database

Tags: c#, sqlite

I just started working on a sample application that only calls some tables on my SQLite database, and I have managed to solve other issues that have happened except this one.

Although I have searched for this, none of the suggested solutions for the connectionstring, permission issues and etc seem to be valid and working for me.  For the permissions, I added the `Everyone` user with full control, and I still get the same error.

Below is the code that I am trying to execute:

```
// calling function
void getRecords2()
    {
        MySqlLite.DataClass ss = new MySqlLite.DataClass();
        DataTable dt = ss.selectQuery("select * from english_words"); 
    }

// the SQLite class that execute the code
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace MySqlLite
{
    class DataClass
    {
        private SQLiteConnection sqlite;

        public DataClass()
        {            
            //This part killed me in the beginning.  I was specifying "DataSource"
            //instead of "Data Source"
            sqlite = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\testwork\db\MrPick.sqlite3.db;Version=3;FailIfMissing=True");

        }

        public DataTable selectQuery(string query)
        {
            SQLiteDataAdapter ad;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                SQLiteCommand cmd;
                sqlite.Open();  //Initiate connection to the db
                cmd = sqlite.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = query;  //set the passed query
                ad = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                ad.Fill(dt); //fill the datasource

                cmd.Dispose();
                sqlite.Dispose();  

            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                //Add your exception code here.
            }
            sqlite.Close();
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I used the following assembly:

```
ADO.NET SQLite Data Provider
Version 1.0.82.0 September 3, 2012
Using SQLite 3.7.14
Originally written by Robert Simpson
Released to the public domain, use at your own risk!
Official provider website: http://system.data.sqlite.org/
```

I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Ok, and what's the exception, and where do you get it?

Comment: Are you sure, is version of your db 3?

Comment: The exception is: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): Unable to open the database file

Comment: The database version if you remove it or keep it no change ,, same error but anyway how to make sure of database file version?

Comment: Does `C:\testwork\db\MrPick.sqlite3.db` exist, with that name and that extension?  I've seen `.db3` and `.sqlite`, but never `.sqlite3.db`.

Comment: yes it exists, and i also added new database using sqlitemanager and its extension was .sqlite, so when i put on the connection string its current extension ".sqlite" it generate error as "table not found" and when i add .db extension "which not appear on the file system" it generate the "unable to open database file"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per your comment, you're getting a "Unable to open database file" error because you're pointing the code at a file that doesn't exist.

A "Table not found" error means it found the database, but not the table you were looking for.  On the other hand, "Unable to open database file" means that it couldn't even find the database, and didn't even bother looking for a table. You're much closer to it working correctly when you're getting "Table not found".

You should change the path back to match the file on disk, then use a tool like the [Firefox SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to confirm that the `english_words` table does exist in your database.

If it doesn't, you should create it with that tool, and if it does, you should post another question here about the "Table not found" error.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: There is behavior in SQLite that if the database specified on the connectionstring not exist it will create new one, so you will always have the "table not found error" in wrong connection string.

Comment: @Nasser - Yes, but you have `FailIfMissing` set to true, so it won't create it if it doesn't find it.

Comment: I faced the same issue but for me the problem was the total length of connectionString was more than 128 characters including "Datasource=C:/<path>/<databaseName>.db". Reduce the length and it should work.

Answer (score 11):

When I ran into this error I had to set `parseViaFramework` in the `SQLiteConnection` constructor to `true`.

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString, true);
connection.Open();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875612/sqlite-c-unable-to-open-the-database-file

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue on the shared hosting server,
My C# code was able to read data from SQLIte db file.
But while add / update data it was throwing Error "unable to open database"

I tried many options suggested on stackoverflow
But after referring
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17780808/2021073
and
https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode
I tried adding **journal mode=Off;** to the Connection string

and it worked for me

sample code

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=G:\dbfolder\sqlite3.db;Version=3;Mode=ReadWrite;journal mode=Off;", true);
```